# Self-teaching graphic design when English is not our mother tongue

Tags: education

I would like to share with you my fear about my opportunity to succeed in learning graphic design.

I am 29 years old and my boyfriend and I decided to change our life, so we moved to London 5 months ago. In France, I tried to go art school but employment opportunities were non-existent and my parents could not help me pay for school, so I gave up.

I speak French all day because of my job, but every morning I tried to learn what I always wanted to do: graphic design.

I would like to know if I can achieve my aim without going to school and learning English & graphic design at the same time? Please, be honest with me.

Comment: I don't understand the question there are graphic designers speaking any language. What exactly do you think is limiting you?

Comment: if you want to learn about graphic design, search for graphic design resources, not Art. There should be plenty of tutorials in French in the Internet. Don't give up and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Design is universal, it doesn't really depend on language since design itself is a language, albeit not in the traditional sense. People who understand design will understand design regardless of their native language. The aesthetics of good design are language agnostic. The ability to produce good design does not depend on the language but on other aspects of the intellect.

That being said, there is the terminology. You can utilize different design techniques without knowing their accepted terms entirely out of good intuition, but if you don't have a good intuition for design, you will pretty much have to learn those techniques the good old way - by reading about them.

Last but not least - the technical aspect - nowadays most design is done digitally, and this involves mastering and using different software products. This is likely the aspect where language will have the most pronounced effect, and not simply casual language, but specific technical terminology. While language itself might not be a mandatory requirement for learning about design, it most certainly is for learning the tools to do that design with.

I am not a native English speaker either, however I learned graphics, mechanical, software and electronic design on my own, all from materials, written in English. I already knew "high school" level English back then, and learned quite a lot more English while learning the various design disciplines, so I can testify that it is indeed a very important factor not only when you learn things, but also when you communicate with others professionally. Surely, there are probably educational materials in other languages as well, I know from experience that Spanish and Russian speaking people are especially dedicated to translating educational materials, but fact is that the bulk of such materials is written in English, so investing time in learning that particular language is certainly a good investment that will come in handy in a lot of areas thorough life. Learning English, and really anything in the digital age is so much easier than it used to be back before the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem. There is a strong design community in the french speaking area.

http://www.ateliermuesli.com/

http://www.ecal.ch/

http://www.andrebaldinger.com/

https://www.swisstypefaces.com/

These are just some links who popped up in my mind within a few seconds.

If that is not good Graphic Design, then I don't know.

My native language is german by the way :)